# Can I use 1 yellow 12V wire to power 2 12V pins?

Tags: pinout, atx

I'm trying to mod a C8220 Dell (mini 18-pin power) from an old ATX supply. I want to know if it's okay to use 1 yellow wire to supply 2 yellow sockets on the 18-pin. Thank you.

Comment: Depends on the gauge of the wire and current draw of the devices, as well as how much voltage drop you can tolerate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, but you should check the max output current of the pin.